# Deedle resampling frame/series

Tags: c#, .net, deedle

I have Python code that uses trade data as input. The trade data is taken from here: https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/spot/daily/trades/ETHUSDT/.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("ETHUSDT-trades-2022-12-16.csv",
                names = ["id", "price", "qty", "quoteQty", "time", "makerBuy", "bestPrice"])

df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit = "ms")
df.set_index("time", inplace = True)

df.price.resample("240T").agg({
    "open": "first",
    "high": "max",
    "low": "min",
    "close": "last"
})
```

Input:

```
    id  price   qty     quoteQty    makerBuy    bestPrice
time                        
2022-12-16 00:00:00.000     1042612060  1266.53     0.0102  12.918606   True    True
2022-12-16 00:00:00.000     1042612061  1266.53     0.0012  1.519836    True    True
2022-12-16 00:00:00.005     1042612062  1266.54     0.0111  14.058594   False   True
2022-12-16 00:00:00.008     1042612063  1266.53     0.0097  12.285341   True    True
2022-12-16 00:00:00.011     1042612064  1266.53     0.0181  22.924193   True    True
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2022-12-16 23:59:59.991     1043495126  1166.82     0.0548  63.941736   True    True
2022-12-16 23:59:59.994     1043495127  1166.83     0.0105  12.251715   False   True
2022-12-16 23:59:59.995     1043495128  1166.83     0.0263  30.687629   False   True
2022-12-16 23:59:59.997     1043495129  1166.82     0.0089  10.384698   True    True
2022-12-16 23:59:59.999     1043495130  1166.83     0.0090  10.501470   False   True

883071 rows × 6 columns
```

Output:

```
time                open        high        low     close
            
2022-12-16 00:00:00     1266.53     1273.87     1265.65     1271.79
2022-12-16 04:00:00     1271.78     1280.06     1267.13     1277.77
2022-12-16 08:00:00     1277.77     1279.27     1205.50     1212.83
2022-12-16 12:00:00     1212.84     1218.23     1195.04     1203.63
2022-12-16 16:00:00     1203.64     1204.58     1183.37     1202.50
2022-12-16 20:00:00     1202.50     1211.99     1155.32     1166.83
```

### Question

I want to migrate the Python code into C#. In fact, I actually did but the thing is, I want to use an actual `DataFrame` framework and not just do everything manually. `Microsoft.Data.Analysis` lacks a lot of features, so I decided to give `Deedle` a try.

```cs
using Deedle;

var df = Frame.ReadCsv("ETHUSDT-trades-2022-12-16.csv",
    hasHeaders: false);

var series = df["Column2"]; // Columns is supposed to be price
series.ResampleEquivalence(date => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(240), aggregate =>
{
});

df.Print();
```

The problem is that I'm unable to set actual names for the columns and do the resampling part. How is that going to work here?

### FYI - that's the manual way

```cs
using System.Globalization;
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using TickDataCustom;

var configuration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { HasHeaderRecord = false };
using var reader = new StreamReader("ETHUSDT-trades-2022-12-16.csv");
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, configuration);

csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<TradeMap>();
var records = csv.GetRecords<Trade>();

var source = records
    .Select(x => new Trade2
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Price = x.Price,
        Quantity = x.Quantity,
        QuoteQuantity = x.QuoteQuantity,
        Time = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(x.Timestamp).UtcDateTime,
        MakerBuy = x.MakerBuy,
        BestPrice = x.BestPrice
    })
    .ToList();

var period = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(240);

var ohlcv = source
    .AsParallel()
    .OrderBy(p => p.Time)
    .Select(d => new
    {
        d.Time,
        d.Price,
        Span = d.Time.Ticks / period.Ticks
    })
    .GroupBy(d => d.Span)
    .Select(g => new Ohlc
    {
        Timestamp = new DateTime(period.Ticks * g.Key),
        Open = g.OrderBy(s => s.Time).First().Price,
        Close = g.OrderBy(s => s.Time).Last().Price,
        Low = g.Min(d => d.Price),
        High = g.Max(d => d.Price)
    })
    .OrderBy(o => o.Timestamp);

foreach (var ohlc in ohlcv)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"T:{ohlc.Timestamp}, O:{ohlc.Open:f2}, H:{ohlc.High:f2}, L:{ohlc.Low:f2}, C:{ohlc.Close:f2}");
}

Console.ReadLine();

public class TradeMap : ClassMap<Trade>
{
    public TradeMap()
    {
        Map(p => p.Id).Index(0);
        Map(p => p.Price).Index(1);
        Map(p => p.Quantity).Index(2);
        Map(p => p.QuoteQuantity).Index(3);
        Map(p => p.Timestamp).Index(4);
        Map(p => p.MakerBuy).Index(5);
        Map(p => p.BestPrice).Index(6);
    }
}

public class Trade
{
    [Index(0)] public string Id { get; set; } = default!;
    [Index(1)] public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Index(2)] public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    [Index(3)] public decimal QuoteQuantity { get; set; }
    [Index(4)] public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    [Index(5)] public bool MakerBuy { get; set; }
    [Index(6)] public bool BestPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Ohlc
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    public decimal Volume { get; set; }
}

public class Trade2
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = default!;
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal QuoteQuantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public bool MakerBuy { get; set; }
    public bool BestPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my solution using Deedle.

First, we load the data as you did. You can then use `IndexColumnsWith` to provide column names. In Deedle, you are not allowed to have duplicate row keys, so I'll create a frame with compisite key - formed by `time` and `id` (to disambiguate). This will let us nicely aggregate later. To do this, you can use `IndexRowsUsing` which lets you select a new row key for each row:

```
using Deedle;

var df =
  Frame.ReadCsv("c:/temp/ETHUSDT-trades-2022-12-16.csv", hasHeaders: false)
    .IndexColumnsWith(new[] { "id", "price", 
        "qty", "quoteQty", "time", "makerBuy", "bestPrice" })
    .IndexRowsUsing(row => 
      Tuple.Create(DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds
         ((long)row["time"]), (int)row["id"]));
```

To do the aggregation, we'll use `ResampleEquivalence` (to create the groups) followed by `Select` (to calcualte OHLC for each group):

```
var prices = df["price"];
var start = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1);

var agg = prices.ResampleEquivalence(kv => {
    // Calculate key - this is the start of the time-block to 
    // which the row belongs (i.e., 0:00, 4:00, 8:00, etc.)
    var h = (int)((kv.Item1 - start).TotalMinutes / 240.0);
    return start.AddMinutes(h * 240);
  }).Select(data => 
    new { 
      open = data.Value.FirstValue(),
      high = data.Value.Max(), 
      close = data.Value.LastValue(),
      low = data.Value.Min() });
```

This produces a series of anonymous records, which you can then turn nicely back into a data frame:

```
Frame.FromRecords(agg).Print();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your descriptive answer! However, this results into: https://i.imgur.com/nznxGwO.png, whereas the Python code does into: https://i.imgur.com/FWsJNk4.png. What is this difference due to?

Comment: @nop I'm sorry, I'm not a pandas expert to immediately spot the difference. You can print the frame at the intermediate step - after the aggregation, but before `Select` and hopefully that will let you see what's different. (I guess the aggregation works subtly differently, but I'm not sure how...)

Comment: 12/17/2022 12:00:00 AM -> 1194.94 1197.57 1155.32 1166.83 - this shouldn't be there. I think the time is not alright. You can take a look at the manual way I did above. It works the same way as the pandas code.

Comment: Could you explain what `var start = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1);` and `var h = (int)((kv.Item1 - start).TotalMinutes / 240.0);` do?

Comment: @nop The idea is to generate unique key for all trades in a certain time range. To do this, we take total minutes since 1/1/2022, divide that by 240 and round the result - so that all trades from e.g., 8:00 to 9:59 end up with the same key. In other words, it divides all possible times into regular 240-minute intervals.

Comment: @TomasPetricek I just posted this question - any chance for a feedback? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75429102/deedle-resample-on-price-column-and-return-time-field-along-with-that